# Checking for installed Triggers onOpen for Google Spreadsheet without using an installable trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a google sheet that has a Google Apps Script connected to it. This script needs installable triggers to function properly. These triggers are installed with the function installTriggers(). This function currently runs when a user manually clicks on a `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu` menu.

```
function installTriggers() {
    if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length != 3) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("sheetEdit").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onEdit().create();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateNotifications").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateLessons").timeBased().everyDays(1).create();
  }
  else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Triggers have already been installed.");
  }
}
```

When these triggers are not installed, certain script functionalities do not work properly. Hence I would like to check if these triggers have already been installed every time a user (might be someone else than the google sheets owner, but also the owner himself) opens the sheet. If there are 0 triggers installed, I would like to give a notification to the user that opened the google sheet through use of an alert popup. It would be nice if it's possible to automatically install the 3 triggers using `installTriggers()` if these are not yet installed, right after clicking away the alert popup.

If all of the 3 necessary triggers have been installed, nothing should happen.

I was planning on using `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()` in an onOpen function to read the amount of triggers already installed.

However, I can't use a simple onOpen trigger, as this trigger would not have the authorization / permission scope to run `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`. I tried this and it gave me the following error in the error log of the GAS editor:

```
"You have no rights to call ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers. Required rights: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp at onOpen(Code:630:32)
```

This would mean I would have to use an installable trigger to run `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()`. However, this is not at all a logical thing to do, because for this installable trigger to run, I would first have to install it. While I am trying to detect sheets that have no triggers installed yet.

**My Question:**
*Does anyone know how I can notify users that no (0) triggers have been installed (and that they're missing out on certain trigger functionalities without knowing it), without using an installable trigger?*

Comment: There is no way to do that, so you have to change your approach to tackle this "issue" and maybe rethink some parts of your solution.

Comment: You can  install `onOpen` for yourself.  It'll run as you, even if others open the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

#### Missing a trigger

```
function checkForTheseTriggers() {
  const rA = ["sheetEdit","updateNotifications","updateLessons"];
  const tA = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t => t.getHandlerFunction());
  if(!rA.every(e => tA.includes(e))) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are missing atleast one essential trigger")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I implemented it in my code to test it and it still threw an error when I refreshed the sheet (in order to trigger onOpen). The error said I did not have permission to call `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers` and said I needed the following scope:  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp. I have already added this scope to my appsscript.json file, but I think it threw an error because the simple trigger onOpen does not have permission to request `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers.` Thanks anyways!